Renovate: Is it possible to group dependencies by registry URL?
PROBLEM
Is there a way to group dependencies by registry URL (so that a separate PR for each registry is created)?
For example I have:

2 npm packages from registry.npmjs.org
2 npm packages from my.registry.example/path/to/repository

and I want Renovate to open 2 PRs, one for the public registry and one for the private one.
TESTS
While reading through the documentation I didn't find any "match" statement with the registryURL (like "matchRegistryURL"), so I'm pretty sure I can't do anything in the packageRules object of the Renovate config.
I also tried some undocumented stuff, hoping it would work, like adding the groupName field in the hostRules instead of packageRules or adding the matchHost in the packageRules instead of hostRules. But Renovate is ignoring those fields when I do so.
WORKAROUNDS
I found two possible (ugly) solutions/workarounds:

run renovate 2 different times with 2 separate configurations (where respectively all public or private registry hosts are disabled)
enforce a package naming convention for private packages and use matchPackageNames or matchPackagePatterns

CONCLUSION
I am curious to know if:

this is possible in a clean way and I just didn't get there
this is not possible, maybe because of some valid reason like "grouping deps by registry URL is stupid :D"


Usually private packages are prefixed so that you can use the prefix as way to filter indeed.

Thanks, Sure. Of course i'm talking about the case where the packages are not prefixed
